# inverse transform of $Z(\omega) =\frac{a}{\alpha-i\omega}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation, laplace-transform

I am stuck at calculating the inverse transorm of  $Z(\omega) =\frac{a}{\alpha-i\omega}$.
Can someone help me please? thanks

Comment: Apply the steps I outlined in an answer to your other IFT question via contour integration: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528410/inverse-ft-of-z-omega-a-frac1i-omega-pi-delta-omega-contour
Actually, this one's even easier.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Fourier transform of the function which is $ae^{\alpha t}$ for $t\le 0$ and 0 for $t> 0$.

Comment: Why should you do it with contour integration?  Your question did not specify this.  And how do we know you mean Fourier transform and not Laplace transform?